# Apollo client mutation with writeQuery not triggering UI update

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a mutation to create a new card object, and I expect it should be added to the user interface after update.  Cache, Apollo Chrome tool, and console logging reflect the changes, but the UI does not without a manual reload.

```
 const [createCard, { loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_CARD, {
    update(cache, { data: { createCard } }) {
      let localData = cache.readQuery({
        query: CARDS_QUERY,
        variables: { id: deckId }
      });

      localData.deck.cards = [...localData.deck.cards, createCard];
;

  client.writeQuery({
    query: CARDS_QUERY,
    variables: { id: parseInt(localData.deck.id, 10) },
    data: { ...localData }
  });
```

I have changed cache.writeQuery to client.writeQuery, but that didn't solve the problem.

For reference, here is the Query I am running...

```
const CARDS_QUERY = gql`
  query CardsQuery($id: ID!) {
    deck(id: $id) {
      id
      deckName
      user {
        id
      }
      cards {
        id
        front
        back
        pictureName
        pictureUrl
        createdAt
      }
    }
    toggleDeleteSuccess @client
  }
`;
```

Comment: How are you requesting that query elsewhere in your app -- `useQuery`? Is there a `no-cache` policy set for that query?

Comment: I updated with a solution I finally came across, apparently deep cloning the data object is a common method to trigger the UI update.  I was using a fairly basic useQuery to show a list of flash cards in a deck, and I used a custom-built popup modal component to Add, edit or delete cards.  My fetch policy is default.  Editing and deleting updates update the cache and UI just fine without needing to use refetch, it was adding cards to an existing deck where I was running into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally ran into a long [Github thread](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3909) discussing their solutions for the same issue.  The solution that ultimately worked for me was deep cloning the data object (I personally used Lodash cloneDeep), which after passing in the mutated data object to cache.writeQuery, it was finally updating the UI.  Ultimately, it still seems like there ought to be a way to trigger the UI update, considering the cache reflects the changes.

Here's the after, view my original question for the before...

```js
const [createCard, { loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_CARD, {
  update(cache, { data: { createCard } }) {
    const localData = cloneDeep(  // Lodash cloneDeep to make a fresh object
      cache.readQuery({
        query: CARDS_QUERY,
        variables: { id: deckId }
      })
    );

    localData.deck.cards = [...localData.deck.cards, createCard];  //Push the mutation to the object

    cache.writeQuery({
      query: CARDS_QUERY,
      variables: { id: localData.deck.id },
      data: { ...localData }  // Cloning ultimately triggers the UI update since writeQuery now sees a new object.
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: When you mutate some object you should make shallow copy, not deep. You don't need to clone everything.

Answer (score 3):

I managed the same result without the `cloneDeep` method. Just using the spread operator solved my problem.

```js
const update = (cache, {data}) => {
  const queryData = cache.readQuery({query: USER_QUERY})
  const cartItemId = data.cartItem.id
  queryData.me.cart = queryData.me.cart.filter(v => v.id !== cartItemId)
  cache.writeQuery({query: USER_QUERY, data: {...queryData}})
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.